# How can I direct exception to a custom error channel in Spring Integration?

Tags: spring, error-handling, spring-integration, sap-commerce-cloud

I set up a custom Hot Folder in SAP Commerce (hybris) with a custom error channel, but I can't get Spring to call my custom error handler `NviMediaErrorHandler`. This the set-up in hot-folder-spring.xml file.

```
<!-- General set-up -->
<int:channel id="nviMediaErrorChannel"/>

<int:service-activator ref="nviMediaErrorHandler" input-channel="nviMediaErrorChannel" method="onError"/>

<bean id="nviMediaErrorHandler" class="com.nvi.core.data.hotfolder.media.task.ErrorHandler">
    <property name="cleanupHelper" ref="nviMediaCleanupHelper"/>
</bean>

<bean id="nviMediaCleanupHelper" class="com.nvi.core.data.hotfolder.media.task.NviMediaCleanupHelper"/>

<bean id="mediaDirectoryNvi" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="#{baseDirectory}/${tenantId}/nvi/media"/>
</bean>


<!-- Image file import process -->
<!-- 1) Scans a directory in a configurable interval and sends files to a configured channel -->
<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="mediaFilesNvi" directory="#{mediaDirectoryNvi}"
                              filename-regex="^\d+(_\d+)?\.(png|jpe?g)" comparator="fileOrderComparator"
                              prevent-duplicates="false">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000"/>
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<!-- 2) Move file to processing/ directory and set up header -->
<file:outbound-gateway request-channel="mediaFilesNvi" reply-channel="mediaFilesNviProcess"
                       directory="#{mediaDirectoryNvi}/processing" delete-source-files="true"/>

<int:service-activator input-channel="mediaFilesNviProcess" output-channel="mediaHeaderSetup"
                       ref="mediaHeaderSetupTask" method="execute"/>

<bean id="mediaHeaderSetupTask" class="com.nvi.core.data.hotfolder.media.task.HeaderSetupTask">
    <property name="catalogs">
        <util:list id="catalogList" value-type="java.lang.String">
            <value>ambestProductCatalog</value>
            <value>egwProductCatalog</value>
            <value>moProductCatalog</value>
            <value>walmartProductCatalog</value>
        </util:list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- 3) Import image file -->
<int:service-activator input-channel="mediaHeaderSetup" output-channel="mediaFileImport"
                       ref="productImageImportTask" method="execute"/>

<bean id="productImageImportTask" class="com.nvi.core.data.hotfolder.media.task.ProductImageImportTask"/>

<!-- Clean up -->
<int:service-activator input-channel="mediaFileImport" ref="fileCleanupTask" method="execute"/>

<bean id="fileCleanupTask" class="com.nvi.core.data.hotfolder.media.task.CleanupTask">
    <property name="cleanupHelper" ref="nviMediaCleanupHelper"/>
</bean>
```

I need errors to go into `nviMediaErrorHandler` and call `com.nvi.core.data.hotfolder.media.task.ErrorHandler` in particular, not the SAP Commerce's out-of-the-box `ErrorHandler`.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
<int:poller fixed-rate="1000" error-channel="nviMediaErrorHandler"/>
```

Comment: "Didn't work" is never enough information. Turn on DEBUG logging to follow the message flow. If you still can't figure it out, post the log and configuration someplace, such as pastebin.

Comment: Thank you for comment @Gary Russell. This is the change I made in configuration: https://pastebin.com/r1QYstXi

These are DEBUG logs: https://pastebin.com/NL7K4T98

As you can see, it goes from ```mediaHeaderSetup``` channel to ```errorChannel``` but I need it to go to ```nviMediaErrorChannel```. I still can't figure it out.

Comment: That doesn't make sense; it appears your updated configuration is not being used. Adding the error channel there updates the `MessagePublishingErrorHandler` in the `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` (which polls the file source). The error handler is injected into the `ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor` which runs the thread. I suggest you run in a debugger; set a breakpoint in `AbstractPollingEndpoint.onInit()` and inspect the error handler.

Comment: OK, my updated config is being used now but I get ```org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No candidate methods found for messages.```

[Debug logs and stacktrace](https://pastebin.com/JZVtYAJJ)

My [custom error handler](https://pastebin.com/styJ9Ah2) has an ```onError``` method as defined in the config file, so I don't understand why no candidate methods found. Could you see why by any chance @Gary?

Comment: Are you sure you are importing the right `MessagingException`? `org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException` - I just tested a similar error handler without any problems.